# Renaming a dataframe column temporarily

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  pandas `DataFrame` and I want to group by a particular column and then rename this column while printing.

Effectively this SQL query

```sql
SELECT name1 AS different_name , name2 AS some_name  FROM table_name 
GROUP BY name 1;
```

but in pandas.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a dataframe from the same data values with different columns. The data is referenced, not copied, so effectively this is just aliasing the column names.

```
# %% Create table with some data and make 'query'
table = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.ones(10)*42, np.ones(10)*12]).T, columns=['name1','name2'])
query = pd.DataFrame(table.values, columns=['different_name1','different_name2'])

# %% Verify that data is a reference, not copy
print(query['different_name1'][0]) # Prints 42.0
table['name1'][0] = 123
print(query['different_name1'][0]) # Npw prints 123.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful!

Comment: If it answers the question, you may consider marking it as the answer.